# AWS CloudFront says public key is invalid/out of limits

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, public-key-encryption, ssh-keygen

I am trying to upload a public key on AWS CloudFront. I generate the key as follows

`ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521`

I have also tried

`ssh-keygen -b 4096`

When I upload it through the console, I get the following error: com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidArgumentException: Your request contains empty/invalid/out of limits RSA Encoded Key (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 08fa98af-0c02-11ea-b06e-d771d01bbfcb)

The result of `ssh -V` is "OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because CloudFront doesn't support keys with length 4096 bits. 
When you run command `openssl rsa -pubout -in key.pem -out pubkey.pem` it by default generates 2048 bit keys which it accepts.

```
The length of the public key for a certificate depends on where you're storing it.

Importing a certificate into AWS Certificate Manager (ACM): public key length must be 1024 or 2048 bits. The limit for a certificate that you use with CloudFront is 2048 bits, even though ACM supports larger keys.

Uploading a certificate to the AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) certificate store: maximum size of the public key is 2048 bits.
```

[CloudFront SSL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html)

Comment: I have tried `ssh-keygen -b 2048` and it did not work either. It seems CloudFront specifically wants OpenSSL

Comment: one question though, cloudfront doesn't allow self signed certificate to be uploaded ,how did upload ? and ssh-key pub file has different format than a public key.

Comment: I simply went to the CloudFront Management Console > Public Key > Add Public Key. I want to use this public key for signed URLs. It's possible I am doing something wrong.

Comment: ahh for signed url, never mind above question but the public key is in RSA key format.  ssh-keygen doesn't do it

Comment: Please ignore my response, I though it's for CloudFront HTTS.

Comment: Update: You can't use this method for signed URLs. This CloudFront Management Console > Public Key > Add Public Key is for something else, and for signed URLs you need to use the account root user. My whole question is moot.

Comment: In 2024 this holds true, per the [CloudFront Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/field-level-encryption.html#field-level-encryption-setting-up-step1):

"To get started, you must create an RSA key pair that includes a public key and a private key...The key size must be 2048 bits."

Answer (score 13):

I solved it by generating a key this way:

`openssl genrsa -out key.pem`

`openssl rsa -pubout -in key.pem -out pubkey.pem`

And uploading the resulting pubkey.pem. I am still not sure the specific reason why my previous method did not work.

Comment: I tried this. This also doesn't work for me. I'm not sure why.

Comment: This works to me

Answer (score 1):

This is the bash script I wrote that can create `RSA` key and do the upload cloudfront public key as well as create cloudfront key group.

```
openssl genrsa -out cloudfront_private_key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in cloudfront_private_key.pem -out cloudfront_public_key.pem
EncodedKey="$(cat ./cloudfront_public_key.pem)"

sed \
-e "s%TEPMLATE_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY%$(echo $EncodedKey)%g" \
./cloudfront_key_config.json.tmpl > ./cloudfront_key_config.json
sed -i 's/- /-\\n/ ; s/ -/\\n-/' ./cloudfront_key_config.json
CloudfrontKeyID=$(aws cloudfront create-public-key --public-key-config file://cloudfront_key_config.json --query 'PublicKey'.'Id' --output text)
echo "CloudFront public key created! now creating cloudfront key group ..."


sleep 10s
sed \
-e "s%TEMPLATE_KEY_ID%$(echo $CloudfrontKeyID)%g" \
./cloudfront_key_group_config.json.tmpl > ./cloudfront_key_group_config.json
CloudFrontKeyGroup=$(aws cloudfront create-key-group --key-group-config file://cloudfront_key_group_config.json --query 'KeyGroup'.'Id' --output text)
echo $CloudFrontKeyGroup
```

And the 2 tmpl files looks like below

```
# cat cloudfront_key_config.json.tmpl 
{
    "CallerReference": "cloudfront-public-key",
    "Name": "CloudFront-Public-Key",
    "EncodedKey": "TEPMLATE_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY",
    "Comment": "CloudFront public key"
}

# cat cloudfront_key_group_config.json.tmpl 
{
  "Name": "CloudFront-key-group",
  "Items": ["TEMPLATE_KEY_ID"],
  "Comment": "Cloudfront key group"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, AWS rejected a malformed (ie raw string, instead of .pem format) RSA 2048 bits, and I had to format it properly (in javascript):

```
          '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' +
          pkey.publicKey
            .split(/(.{64})/)
            .filter((s) => s)
            .join('\n') +
          '\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n',
```